# What are the differences between [index], [indexing], and [google-index]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What are the differences between these tags?

- [index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index)
- [indexing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing):

  > The process of recording where particular words occur. In the web context search engines crawl the web and make a list of which pages have particular words - this is the index.
- [google-index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-index):

  > All web resources crawled by Google bots and recorded in Google databases.

In my opinion, they are all the same, and we should merge them. I propose to put it as [search-engine-indexing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine-indexing).

What do you think?

Comment: Although google-index technically distinctly refers to Google's index I think 99.99% of the time, or more, it can be replaced with a combination of this tag and the google tag. But at the very least I agree the first two tags should be combined and made a synonym of `search-engine-indexing`.

Comment: what is the difference between google-index and Google's index? I google both and they are just the same

Comment: `search-engine-indexing` applies to any search engine, `google-index` is specific to Google. If someone is asking a question specific to Google this would make sense to use. But as I said above, I can see using `google` with `search-engine-indexing` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see the word "refers" in "google-index technically distinctly refers to Google's index", so I thought there was another term in webmaster that also in the form "Google's index", and one should be careful in using it

Comment: I primarily agree with John, which I usually do 99.99% of the time, or more, but with a slight variation on this 0.01% deviation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why these tags appear similar and should be merged, but there are some dissimilarities in the context of a Webmaster:

- `index` can be used when referring to a file (such as the default
  index file of a web site or web server). There are a few questions
  which have used this tag in that context. For example,
  [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123210/is-it-safe-to-give-write-permission-to-index-php-file)
  and
  [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118845/redundant-non-gzip-index-file)
  one.
- `indexing` could reference other topics, such as indexing a database,
  but in the context of this site's focus (i.e., for Webmasters, not
  [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)), the tag's
  Info seems to be fairly descriptive. It could however be even more
  descriptive to create a tag called `search-engine-indexing` as you
  suggested, and make `indexing` a synonym of that as John had
  suggested.
- Whereas `search-engine-indexing` would apply to all search engines,
  `google-index` is specific to just Google. Information that applies
  to Google might not apply to the other search engines. For that
  reason, it should probably have its own tag, while
  `search-engine-indexing` could be used to reference this in general.

So to recap, we should create a tag for `search-engine-indexing` and make `indexing` a synonym of that, but leave `google-index` as it is so users will know that the question is specific to only Google.

**Update:**

Thanks to Stephen's hard work, the `indexing` tag was merged with a newly created `search-engine-indexing` tag. All of the questions using the `index` tag were either re-tagged with `search-engine-indexing` or a newly created, more descriptive `directory-index` tag. The `index` tag should therefore automatically be removed from the site by the system in a day's time since it's no longer being used.

+1 to the community for making the site just a little bit better!

Comment: You don't mention it in your recap, but I think you want leave [Tag:index] alone as well?   Maybe it would be better to create [Tag:directory-index] to differentiate uses of [Tag:index] between search engine indexes and directory indexes.  It could be a lot of work to go through and re-tag all the questions though.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Indeed, I had incoming notifications and got distracted... If we wanted to be thorough about it, we could go through the questions marked with `index` that are really about "search engine indexing" and edit those to be tagged with a newly created `search-engine-indexing` tag instead (as covered above). Then we could create the more specific `directory-index` tag you suggested and edit the remaining questions tagged with `index` to use that tag instead. The `index` tag would then no longer be used by any questions and removed in a day.

Comment: If you follow that, and feel inclined, go for it :-) Otherwise I'll get to it in a day or so.

Comment: I merged [Tag:indexing] to [Tag:search-engine-indexing].  I also went through all the questions tagged [tag:index] and re-tagged them as either [tag:directory-index] or [tag:search-engine-indexing].  I also created the [tag wiki for directory-index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/directory-index/info).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Great - thanks for the heavy lifting!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller and dan: I was thinking about creating `file-index` and `database-index`. Maybe `file-index` should be a synonym of `directory-index` as well?

Comment: I don't think we'll get questions about database indexes here.  That would be a better tag for the database site.